# Can the models.py file created by Django be used by another python file to fill in a database?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have followed the tutorial (parts 1 and 2) on the Django site (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/) and have managed to create a couple folders and to connect to my website. My app is called 'app', so my folder structure looks a bit like:

- **mainFolder**
- ---**__*init*__**.py
- ---test.py
- ---**djangoSite** (created by Django)
- ------ manage.py
- ------ **djangosite**
- --------- other .py files
- ------ **app**
- ----------**__*init*__**.py
- --------- models.py
- --------- other .py files

I changed the models.py file to be something like:

```
class Result(models.Model):
    options = models.CharField(max_length = 1000, unique = False)
    reverse = models.DecimalField(decimal_places = 6, max_digits = 12)
```

test.py currently runs a couple tests on some other classes. What I want is for my test.py class to run these tests and save the results in a database (in columns 
and reverse). I was hoping to do something like this in my test.py class:

```
import models.py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    optionResult = someTestsThatRuns
    reverseResult = someOtherTestThatRuns
    models.Result c;
    c.options = optionResult 
    c.reverse = reverseResult
```

I'd like for the last two lines to save the result in the database. 
Is this possible? How would I import the models.py from the app folder?

Thank you

***EDIT***:
When I say someTestsThatRuns, these aren't unit tests. They are practically a function that returns a list and some strings with either 'PASS' or 'FAIL'. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an empty `__init__.py` file in the app folder so Python treats the directory as a package. Then do:

```
from app.models import Result

optionResult = someTestsThatRuns
reverseResult = someOtherTestThatRuns
c = Result()
c.options = optionResult 
c.reverse = reverseResult
c.save()
```

That will save 'c' to the database.

Note that Django's test suite can create its own test database, which runs tests on a separate database. You can read more about Django testing here.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/?from=olddocs

Comment: Hi David and thanks for the first response! I was actually thinking of doing what you suggested (and tried before posting this question), but I became stuck at an error from my models.py file saying `'line 4: from django.db import models' - ImportError: No module named db` =/

Comment: Also, I added the edit after reading from the site you sent me. My tests aren't unit tests nor do they test the Django site; they are functions that run some c++ classes and get some results in strings and lists. Sorry for the confusion =(

Comment: Go to the command line, start python, and then type import django.db. See if it raises an error. If it raises an error, Python isn't picking up the django package on its search path. 

From the command line, import sys followed by print sys.path will tell you what directories are on Python's search path. Django should be installed under one of those directories, usually in site-packages. 

If import django.db works from the command line, make sure the right Python interpreter is chosen in whatever development environment you're working in.

Answer (score 1):

***FIXED*** As David mentioned in the comments, the environment variable was indeed not set. Since I was in Windows, what I had to do was Start -> Computer -> Properties -> advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables -> add Environment Variable.

There I added 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' and its location as 'C:\path\to\your\settings.py' Afterwards, in command prompt, I had to do the following:

```
enter python
>import sys
>import os
>sys.path.append(r"C:\location\to\settings.py")
>from django.core.management import setup_environ
>setup_environ(settings)
>sys.path.append(os.getcwd() + '\\from\\current\\to\\models.py'
>from models import Result
```

This is all explained at http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/ , though I did find it somewhat difficult to understand. Another problem I had with importing my models is that there were TWO folders named exactly the same (djangoSite), so when importing, the computer had some issues trying to figure out which one. I had to rename, remove, reset environment variable and recheck all of the paths I have throughout my files =/

I am sorry if my explanations aren't the best, I barely understood what I did, but I do hope this will help other in the future